# Error with migration postgress, i have two columns over, why?

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

i have a migration, i only have four colums, id, name, last_name and email but when i do a query from postman it show me other colums over `SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"lastName\", \"email\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\"` what is the wrong?

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('User', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('User');
  }
};
```

and when i used my service

```
static async getAllUsers() {
    try {
      const users = await database.User.findAll();
      console.log('COnsOLE ', users)
      return users
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

i get this error from postman:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": {
        "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
        "parent": {
            "length": 104,
            "name": "error",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "code": "42P01",
            "position": "73",
            "file": "parse_relation.c",
            "line": "1180",
            "routine": "parserOpenTable",
            "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"lastName\", \"email\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\";"
        },
        "original": {
            "length": 104,
            "name": "error",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "code": "42P01",
            "position": "73",
            "file": "parse_relation.c",
            "line": "1180",
            "routine": "parserOpenTable",
            "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"lastName\", \"email\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\";"
        },
        "sql": "SELECT \"id\", \"name\", \"lastName\", \"email\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\" FROM \"Users\" AS \"User\";"
    }
}
```

i before used this commands many times: `sequelize db:migrate` and `sequelize db:migrate:undo`

this is my git repository: https://github.com/x-rw/basePostgresExpressjs

you should situate in server directory and write `npm run dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your sequelize model instance have updatedAt and createdAt fields and because of that it queries the database to get these two fields too. But in your migration file there is no updatedAt and createdAt fields. So your database table does not have these columns.

You have two options, if you really don't want to use updatedAt and createdAt you should specify that while initializing your sequelize model instance. [Check the api reference.](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-init) You should see options.timestamps. You can set it to false.

```
class YourModel extends Sequelize.Model { }
YourModel.init(
    {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notNull: true,
                notEmpty: true,
                len: [2, 100]
            }
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize: sequelizeInstance,
        timestamps: false // This is what you need.
    }
);
```

If you want to use it however, check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125741/how-to-set-mysql-datetype-length-with-sequelize-cli) to generate correct migrations.

Comment: how can i put false?

Comment: Check the answer. I have added an example.

Comment: i have this problem ReferenceError: sequelizeInstance is not defined

Comment: but this worrked for me {
  freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
  timestamps: false,
  underscored: true
}